# How to send json string from backing bean to external javascript file?

Tags: json, jsf, jsf-2, google-visualization

i have external javascript file for drawing google charts
and in this js file i want to access backing bean to get json string.

**js file:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(typeof(google)!= undefined){
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'],callback: drawChart});
    }
};

function drawChart() {
    var jsonStr=#{myBean.jsonStr} // i want to be able to do something like that
    var data_recSent = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonStr);
    //
    //
}
```

if there's no possible solution/workaround for this case, please advise about other solutions.

Comment: If this is a static javascript file, you'll have to set up a service that you can query via AJAX to grab your data.

Answer (score 0):

best solution i have found so far, is to store the json string in hidden input, and then get the value of this hidden input in the js file.

Comment: If you're willing to use global javascript variables, you can skip the hidden input and add it directly to a global variable in your main HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of `#{myBean.jsonStr}` is big, I would suggest you to make it cached by browser as follows:

Use a separated js file to keep this json:

**myjson.js**

```
var jsonStrGobal=JSON_PLACEHOLDER;
```

**In the html header**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="myjson.js?version=#{myBean.jsonVersion}" />
```

**myjson.js** is not stored physically, but loaded by a servlet or a backing bean, `JSON_PLACEHOLDER` is replaced by your json, this servlet of backing bean will set the `Cache-control` on http response header to make browser cache it. Servlet can be registered in web.xml, backing bean can be declared in pages.xml as a page action.

Increase myBean.jsonVersion whenever the content of json changes so that browser gets notified.